# Attempt to assign property "approve" on null

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know what I have missed. Please help me find the solution, really appreciate that.

So this is my Route

```
Route::get('/form/approval', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'approval'])->name('form.approval');

Route::post('/toggle-approve','ProductController@approval');
```

This is my Model

```
namespace App\Models;
`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name', 'chemical_name', 
        'approve'
    ];
    
}
```

This is my Controller

```
    class ProductController extends Controller
{      

    public function approval(Request $request)
    {

        $product= Product::find($request->productId);
        $approveVal->approve=$request->approve;
        if($approveVal=='on'){
            $approveVal=1;
        }else{
            $approveVal=0;
        }

        $product->approve=$approveVal;
        $product->save();

        return back();
    }}
```

This is my View

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Approval Management</div>
  
                <div class="card-body">
                        
                    @if (Session::has('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
                    @endif
                    <table class="table table-bordered mb-5">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-danger">
                    <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Chemical Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Supplier Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Location Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ $product->product_name }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $product -> chemical_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product -> supplier_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $product -> location_name }}</td>
                    <td>
                    <form action="{{url('/toggle-approve')}}" method="POST">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                  <input <?php if($product->approve == 1){echo "checked";}?>  type="checkbox" id=approve name='approve' >       
                     
                     <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="{{$product->id}}">    
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Done">
                  
              </form>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="{{  url('/form/details/'.$product->id)  }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">View Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                   
     
         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

I tried  defined the value=approve in the blade but still got error. I don't know whether the error coming from the controller or somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I want to approve the Product user had filled.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error Attempt to assign property "approve" on null 127.0.0.1:8000/form/approval @apokryfos

Comment: $product->approve=$approveVal;

this one is highlighted as error

Comment: it seems that ` $product= Product::find($request->productId);` does not find a product with the given id, and therefore the variable $product is null. You should do a check in there if Product::find() does actually return a valid product

Comment: `$approveVal->approve=$request->approve;`

where is $approveVal defined?

I think this is the error and has to be `$approveVal = $request->approve;`

Comment: check whether you are getting a productId or not  in this ```$request->productId```

Comment: Thank you to all of you for replying to my post, I have changed the productId to product_name and it's work. Thanks guys.